# Disabled users in AWS Amplify Cognito still can access to data in the API

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

Graphql Api and Auth added on a brand new project.

I go to Amplify console -> myapp -> api -> GraphQL API and click on View in AppSync. On the run query part, I run A sample query like this:

```
{
  listTodos {
    items {
        name
    }
  }
}
```

And the response is a UnauthorizedException. This is expected and working right.

Then, if I log in with a cognito user, the response is some example TODOS. This is also fine.

If I go to Cognito and disable the user, I can still run the query. I was a expecting an unauthorized or something else than actually being able to query for my data (as the **user is disabled**).

Answer (score 2):

Cognito access and ID tokens are valid for [one hour from the time they are issued](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token). As long as the user's token is still valid and unexpired, they will be authorized to access the GraphQL API [regardless of the user's existence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52031831).

Cognito [does not offer the ability to revoke access/ID tokens](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3435), although the refresh token can be revoked immediately using the [GlobalSignOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html) API call.

One workaround for this limitation is [custom logic](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3435#issuecomment-576258802) which can be implemented within your application to verify if the user exists within the user pool/is in a valid state prior to initiating the request with the GraphQL API.